# i want to redirect from my custom button to 'New product' adding page (already existing) in magento 2 . The link given below is changing each time

Tags: php, magento2

```
<?php

namespace MagePal\AdminSalesOrderViewButton\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View as OrderView;

class View
{

    public function beforeSetLayout(OrderView $subject)
    {
        $subject->addButton(
            'order_custom_button',
            [
                'label' => __('Add Product'),
                'class' => __('add'),
                'id' => 'add_new_product',
                'onclick' => 'setLocation(".../catalog/product/new/set/4/type/simple/key/aa28309bce371172005ac8f5ec8533a866ec59cdc21014b3a7a9e8560a149d18/")'
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: The title isn't the body of the question. I suggest you to make the title more clear then add full explaination of the issue, of what you want and what you have. You can read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> ?php namespace
> Tigren\SapIntegration\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order; use
> Magento\Framework\UrlInterface; use
> Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface; use
> Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View; class ViewPlugin

```
{
    private $urlBuilder;
    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    
    public function beforeSetLayout(View $subject, LayoutInterface $layout)
    {
        $subject->addButton('sap_log_detail', [
            'label' => __('SAP Log Detail'),
            'class' => 'clone',
            'id' => 'sap-log-detail',
            'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getCloneUrl($subject->getOrderId()) . '\')'
        ]);
        return [$layout];
    }

    private function getCloneUrl($orderId)
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
            'sap_integration/sapLog/LogDetail',
            ['order_id' => $orderId]
        );
    }
}
```